# How to mock a function that takes an already defined lambda function and have coverage over lambda function

Tags: c++, googletest

I am learning unit testing using googletest and am unsure how to cover a function.
In short, I need to get coverage over lambda function (lets say L), defined inside a mother function M. M calls a function C (defined in another file) that takes as argument lambda function L (a callback). I am writing a unit test for M, and need to call M, mocking the outside function M while also ensuring C is mocked and L is covered properly.

In short, object->M has L and M calls C(L).

Is there a way in google test to do this?

General shape of what I've already tried:

```
    /* source code */
    /* header */
    struct Object
        {/*struct methods*/ 
        //M declaration
        int M();
        };

    /* cpp file */
    int M()
    {
        /* some operations */
        auto L = [](int number){/* operations, returns 0; */};

        int store; //storing the result of C
        store = C(L);
    }

    /* other file */
    int C(int* L(int))
    {
        /* some operations */
        L(1);

        return some_int;
    }
```

Unit test file code:

```
    #include <gmock/gmock.h>
    #include <gtest.h>

    using ::testing::Return;
    using ::testing::ReturnRef;
    using ::testing::DoAll;
    using ::testing::SetArgReferee;
    using ::testing::SetArgPointee;
    using ::testing::SetArrayArgument;
    using ::testing::_;

   /* mock class*/
   class MockedFunctions
   {
   public:
       /* going to put 5 ints for the sake of the example */
       MOCK_METHOD1(C, int(int));
   };

   class TestObject : public ::testing::Test
   {
   public:
       TestObject(){}
       ~TestObject(){}
   protected:
       Object *objectInstance;
       virtual void SetUp()
       {    objectInstance = new Object;}
       virtual void TearDown()
       {    delete objectInstance;}
   };

   /* test for function */
   TEST_F(TestObject, test_M)
   {
       MockedFunctions test_C;

       EXPECT_CALL(test_C, C(_))
           .Times(1)
           /* don't care about passed number to L */
           .WillOnce(DoALL (SetArgPointee<0>(L(3)), Return(0));
       /* coud put EXPECT_EQ as well */
       objectInstance->M();
   }
```

This gives me an error at .WillOnce stating L was not declared in this scope.

Note that I do not care about the contents of L, as long as they are covered. What I have found so far regarding this topic suggested to mock my lambda function L, which I do not want to do here, since I need coverage over its code as part of function M.

While I am not required, in this case, to use strictly the GTest style (as my tutor did not know how to proceed with this L function coverage) and could use a stub for C that would force the usage of L (I have this version implemented at the moment to be able to compile with the rest of the code), is it nonetheless possible to obtain this coverage using strictly a googletest style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found a solution and posting it for reference;

My solution was to find a way to store the callback method I was interested in inside a container, creating auxiliary methods for this and to obtain some output from that vector.

1. Inside the class containing the MOCK_METHODX() declarations, I first used a typedef to identify my function more easily.
2. Then, declared in a private block the vector and a void pointer which will be used to pass the function around.
3. Auxiliary methods to get contents at position x of the vector (I had cases where I would run my mocked function multiple times inside a test and thus wanted to see how each call performed), adding to vector, clearing contents (reset for other tests) and so forth.
4. Static pointer of type MockedFunctions used to provide an object to "resume" normal mock control behavior after our desired data has been extracted.

   ```
   //inside my header file.
   #include <gmock/gmock.h>
   #include <vector>

   class MockedFunctions {
       public:
          //lets say function L has params (int, void*)
          typedef int (myCb) (int arg_from_cb_L, void* objptr_from_cb_L));
          MockedFunctions(){}
          virtual ~MockedFunctions(){}

          //giving C more arguments than just the callback L
          MOCK_METHOD2(C, int(int arg1, int(*L)(int, void*));
       private:
          //note due to namespace limitations, I'm including the std prefix
          std::vector<myCb> callback_storage;
          void *cb_obj_copy;
       public:
          /* Multiple public blocks just for readability purposes.
           * Note the internal usage of vector methods.
           */
          void cb_clear(){
              if(callback_storage.empty())
              {
                  callback_storage.clear();
              }
          }
          void cb_add(myCb callback){
              callback_storage.push_back(callback);
          }
          myCb* cb_result_at(int i){
              return callback_storage.at(i);
          }
          //to store one of the params from the passed callback
          void cb_copy_obj(void* obj){
              cb_obj_cb = obj;
          }
          void cb_get_obj_copy(){
              return cb_obj_copy;
          }
      };

      class TestMethods : public ::testing::Test
         {
         public:
             static std::unique_ptr<MockedMethods> testMockedMethods;
             TestMethods(){
                 /* as we call other methods from MockedMethods apart from C,
                  * it would trigger warnings. Using NiceMock hides them for
                  * cleaner output.
                  */
                 testMockedMethods.reset(new ::testing::NiceMock<MockedMethods>());
             }
             ~TestMethods() override{
                 testMockedMethods.reset();
             }
             virtual void SetUp() override {}
             virtual void TearDown() override {}
         };
   ```

Now, inside my cpp file, I defined C and instantiated the pointer.

```
              std::unique_ptr<MockedMethods> TestObject::testMockedMethods(new MockedMethods() );
              int C ( int arg1, int(*L)(int arg1_cb, void* arg2_cb)){
                  TestMethods::testMockedMethods->cb_add(L);
                  TestMethods::testMockedMethods->cb_copy_obj(arg2_cb);
                  /* to avoid complications, took L's return type of int and put a 0
                   * directly, we don't care at this point since we will overload the
                   * method afterwards.
                   */
                  return TestMethods::testMockedMethods->C(arg1, 0);
              }
```

As for the actual testing, placed where you see fit:

```
       class TestCaseClass : public TestMethods
       {
           public:
               TestCaseClass(){}
               ~TestCaseClass(){}
           protected:
               //Here, object is the struct name mentioned previously in the question.
               Object *instance;
               // ...

               virtual void SetUp()
               {
                   instance = new Object();
                   // ...
               }
               virtual void TearDown()
               {
                  delete instance;
               }
       };

       TEST_F(TestCaseClass, test_M)
       {
           // testing method M from struct Object

           /* Run tests normally on C, results will be stored. By our definition, a different object
            * will be the one calling C, so pay attention to it.
            */
           EXPECT_CALL(*testMockedMethods, C(_, _))
               .Times(1)
               .WillOnce(Return(1))
           // I noticed at this point M above did not return anything, suppose it returns store
           EXPECT_EQ(instance->M(), 1);

           // Now to get coverage or data from our callback. First, get the method in cb_obj
           MockedMethods::myObj* cb_method = testMockedMethods->cb_result_at(0);
           // Now get one of its arguments, like that void*. Note we're using our get-ers
           void* mock_object = testMockedMethods->cb_get_obj_copy();
           /* And finally, call our method, finally getting coverage. You can pass 
            * various parameters for branching.
            */
           cb_method(0, mock_object);

           // Don't forget we clear the vector of contents in case we re-use it in another test.
           testMockedMethods->cb_clear();
       }
```

While not the most direct solution, it proved effective and I tried to include a few usage cases one might encounter in creating their tests.

Happy coding!